# Why is compatability mode breaking the javascript on my website but only in HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, compatibility

I have an application which must be put into compatibility mode on IE11 to function properly. This seems to work perfectly when I am using it over http, but as soon as I try to access the website via https many of the javascript elements seem to break. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Could be a matter of security. Browsers disallow the use of resources from mixed schemas (http:// + https://). (in case you include external resources). Did you look into the dev-console?

Comment: All I got was an "unspecified error" in the dev console.

Comment: Did you try your site in other browsers? Maybe they are a bit more verbose

Comment: IE features the "Compatibility View" for a few versions now, which is enabled by default. You can emulate older IE versions by adding meta tags specifying the version, but it is known to mess up your JS/JQuery. I do not know why it is restricted to HTTPS for you, but maybe you'll want to give it a go. Just google it or check out this blog entry, hope it helps! http://jwcooney.com/2011/12/05/internet-explorer-compatibility-mode-breaks-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

sorry bad english :/

in HTTPS protocol, all resources external not secure will be deactivate
you can ingrate in your site all files external not secure
or replace them with others secure

exp: http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js

by : https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js

rmq: if you have the certificate ssl

you can redirect all urls no certificate

yoursite.com

www.yoursite.com

with your url

https://www.yoursite.com